# Error al enviar datos al WebService del SII de Chile

Tags: asp.net, .net, webservice, soap, tokens

Existe un Webservice(SOAP) del SII(servicio puesto interno de Chile), cuya dirección es `https://ws2.sii.cl/WSREGISTRORECLAMODTECERT/registroreclamodteservice?wsdl`

He establecido la referencia de servicio que contiene los métodos que aparecen en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo mi código en C#, en donde hago una prueba para aceptar una factura electrónica.

```
        MiServicio.RegistroReclamoDteServiceClient oCliente = new MiServicio.RegistroReclamoDteServiceClient();
        //oCliente.ClientCredentials.IssuedToken.CacheIssuedTokens = true;
        var aceptacion = oCliente.ingresarAceptacionReclamoDoc("94668000",
            "1",
             "33",
             "784060",
             "ACD"
             );

        if (aceptacion.codResp==1) {

            var p = 1;
        }
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto, me sale error:

> InvalidOperationException:
>   Namespace='http://ws.registroreclamodte.diii.sdi.sii.cl' no es
>   compatible con SOAP rpc o literal. El elemento contenedor tiene que
>   estar incompleto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer, creo que el motivo es que el webservice pide algún token, pero si fuese así, no se como obtenerlo y como asignarlo.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, le agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Nota: Saque información de [esta pagina](http://lenguajedemaquinas.blogspot.com/2017/05/web-service-de-consulta-y-registro-de.html), pero al parecer tiene algunos métodos desactualizados, de todas formas lo dejo si os sirve de algo.

Hay una pagina que se obtiene el token:
http://www.appoctava.cl/ws/WebService.php?wsdl
 pero cuando creo la referencia de servicio, en el codigo C# no me detecta el nombre de servicio, como por ejemplo al primer servicio le llamé MiServicio.

Comment: Lo probe y falta el acceso con Token. Lo obtuviste?

Comment: @RamiroBarone, no, por lo menos en que parte entregaría el token, sintacticamente en C#?

Comment: @RamiroBarone, en esta pagina http://www.appoctava.cl/ws/documentacion-factura-electronica-net/
dice como obtener el token, pero no me detecta el nombre del servicio que le coloco en C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el token que te falta se agrega en el header de la solicitud:
[image: Header]

-Cómo se obtiene el token? Son 2 pasos:

1-Obtener la semilla (el string lo puedes serializar para usarlo si quieres):

```
using (CrSeedService cliente = new CrSeedService());
string response =  cliente.getSeed();
```

2-Obtener el token, este se obtiene enviando la semilla firmada con el certificado.

```
using (GetTokenFromSeedService cliente = new GetTokenFromSeedService());
var seedfirmada;
string token =  cliente.getToken(seedfirmada);
```